# VPC creation failed using AWS CDK: AddressLimitExceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am creating a VPC through aws cdk on vscode. While running the cdk bootstrap it is creating a stack successfully but after running `cd deploy` it is showing `vpc creation failed` and `ROLLBACK` is also not created.

> Error Code: AddressLimitExceeded

I have tried creating vpc earlier with same approach and it was a success but now I am trying to create another vpc with same approach its showing several errors after deploying. Please help me understand and resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you check how many EIPs you have? I think you reach the max EIPs.

Comment: From [Error codes for the Amazon EC2 API - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html): "`AddressLimitExceeded`: You've reached the limit on the number of Elastic IP addresses that you can allocate."

Answer (score 1):

Base on your capture, you reached the maximum EIPs (5 EIPs), you need to delete the not in use EIPs or submit a ticket to increase your quota.

Comment: I got 5 EIPs already but in a different region. I the region I am trying to deploy got no EIPs.

Comment: Maybe you have mis-config of region in your code. Btw, you can go to  ```https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/``` to check the quota.

Comment: I got no VPC EIPs and classic EIPs in my region, still do I have to increase quota limit?